Every line has a mid-point. True or False?
Every line has a mid-point. True or False?
I thought obviously it's true. Book says it's false.
A line is defined as containing at least two points. Thus if there are at least two points, then there must be a mid-point. So why do I feel I am correct and the book is giving the wrong answer?

A line is a nonfinite object.
every line segment had a mid-point, yes.

The question is asking about postulates about a line. But all lines have a mid-point!

How are you going to define the midpoint of a non-finite object ?

Does non-finite mean infinite?

As far as I know, yes

I see...so the line stretches on indefinitely, so we can't define the ends. Therefore it is not possible to have a mid-point.

Yes. I could be wrong though.

Thanks man you helped me understand.
